# Smallest regular pentagon covering a regular heptagon

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, maxima-minima

A friend gave me a puzzle that seems very very tricky to me, and that we couldn't solve so far.

It asks for the minimum size of a pentagon that covers a regular heptagon with sides of length $1$.

It is **not neccesary** for the polygons to be **concentric**. What struggles me is that playing with Geogebra the optimal configuration seems very unintuitive to me, and calculations become very ugly. Is it that I am missing something? Maybe there is a closed formula for such minimal length (using sines or cosines of possibly ugly multiples of $\pi$) and I can't get it.

Comment: Makes me think of the Reuleaux triangle and drilling square holes with triangular bits.